# Slick slider does not load the first slide on transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I have a problem when using the infinite slider, when moving from the last slide to the first, a white slide appears, and only then the first one, there is no smooth transition. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCStf.png)

Maybe there are some loading options for the slider?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**When init event is fired, I removed .slick-active and added .reset-animation. reset-animation resets scale of .slick-slide-image to 1 with 0s of transition.**

**Then after 1ms of delay, I removed .reset-animation and added .slick-active to animate the first the slide.**

Now my have the following code in my JS and CSS (sharing it jus in case anyone else is stuck on the same).

Example JS:
$('.your class or id').slick('reinit');

Once it get reinit then it will help you out to have the animation.

Please refer more for brief detail:
https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/2018